# Android Layout Xml place URL with different visible text

Tags: android, layout

I am working on a common navigation header (Navigation Drawer - the header) for my apps as it is inefficient to copy/paste the designs from app to app.

Now I have several controls in this header, including three buttons to follow me on G+, find my developer page on google play and rate the current app. It looks like this:

[image]

Now my question is:
While I know that URL's are automatically detected and made clickable, is it possible to do the same, but the visible text is "Follow", "Apps" or "Rate"?

In other words, I do not have so much room to display the full url to the play store and so on... 
I want to show "Apps", but navigate to "play.google...blah"

Is this possible only in the xml layout, without any code?

I know, I can make a .aar library and navigate there from java after the button click. I am curious, if it can be done in pure xml.

Answer (score 1):

```
<string name="text_with_ref">"<a href='http://www.freepik.com/'>Freepik.com</a>"</>

<TextView
 android:text="@string/text_with_ref"
/>
```

in Java:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Thanks. While this works in display, it does not open the link without java interaction. So it seems, it can't be done in pure xml. But anyway, thanks for this hint --- I didn't think it could be THAT easy, just to place a "a href" in the text... :)

Comment: @Grisgram try  android:autoLink="all" on a TextView with no Java code